# add inout array in constraint variable

Tags: swift

i am not able to add inout array in constraint variable

```
import Foundation
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    var someRight = [Int]()
    for index in 0...(A.count) {
        someRight.append(A[index])
    }
    return -1
}

var result : Int = solution(&Int: [6,7,8])   ///Here i get error
```

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why are you using `inout`? What's `someRight` for?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a __specific problem or error__ and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."_

Comment: `0...A.count` will crash as you try to index the array by its `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here. First, `solution(&Int: [6,7,8])` is not how to call the function. The `&` in front of the label `Int` is not how to pass in an `inout`. The `&` should be in front of the variable itself. Second, `Int` is not the label for that function. In fact, it has an unnamed label (the underscore in `solution(_:)`, so the method call is just `solution(&[6,7,8])`.

With those syntax errors out of the way, the compiler can help you more. Now it will tell you that you are not passing in a mutable variable. We have to tell the compiler that the array you are going to pass in is mutable, so we must declare a new variable: `var arr = [6,7,8]`. Then we can pass that variable into the function.

Finally, there is an out of bounds error in your for loop. You should use `..<` instead of `...`. `...` will attempt to access an element of the array that is one index more than the array has. With all these fixed, you should be good to go.

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    var someRight = [Int]()
    for index in 0..<(A.count) {
        someRight.append(A[index])
    }
    return -1
}

var arr = [6,7,8]
var result : Int = solution(&arr)
```

Comment: You missed a few additional issues. 1. Why use `inout` at all? `A` isn't being reassigned or modified in any way inside `solution`. 2. What's the point of the `solution` method? `someRight` can be created simply by assigning `A` to it. But the result isn't even being used. The return value is hardcode to `-1`. It's all pointless.

Comment: This entire program can be reduced to `var result = -1`.